# Custom MATCH function in conditional formatting not fully working in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, count, conditional-formatting, counting

I've been working on a sheet that helps me track matching numbers.
I used the MATCH function using custom conditional formatting.
To help me track easily, **I want the cells to be highlighted when the value matches with the other column** *(column B and column I)*.

My first attempt was not successful since it did not highlight anything *(see sheet: 1st attempt)*.
So I tried to add another column (column J) hoping it will work.
It kinda worked but not the way I wanted to *(see sheet: 2nd attempt)*.

The format in Column B seems to be a NUMBER.
The format in Column B seems to be a TEXT.
The format in Column B seems to be a NUMBER.

I am really confused and stuck now on what to do next. Your help will really be appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the link to the document in case you want to have a glimpse of it. It is editable, btw.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pCT5wWYOpaXT6t8UOPSIzUomz_sZJKgxekASHj4ZPCU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=(INDEX(COUNTIF(RIGHT(B$3:B, 7), RIGHT(I3, 7))))*(I3<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: this works, thankyou!however, the left side did not highlight the numbers that matched on the right side.

Comment: so i tried applying the same formula, and it works perfectly. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Added solution CF to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pCT5wWYOpaXT6t8UOPSIzUomz_sZJKgxekASHj4ZPCU/edit#gid=668828646):

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH($I4&"","(?:^|\s)"&TEXTJOIN("(?:\s|$)|(?:^|\s)",1,$B$4:$B&"")&"(?:\s|$)"))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: this works also, but my problem with this is the google sheet takes a long time to process the functions :'(